# How to store uploaded file into folder using CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

How to store **upload**  file into folder using CodeIgniter?

Comment: What have you tried? You may refer to this article http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html.

Comment: You need to define the upload path in $config['upload_path']= 'your path'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Be sure with your gallery folder it must be in root alongside with application folder name gallery

```
$config['upload_path']='./gallery/';
$config['allowed_types']='gif|png|jpeg|jpg';
$config['max_size']='100';
$config['max_width']='1024';
$config['max_height']='700';
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$this->upload->do_upload('upload_photo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this code inc controller. This the function when u hit the upload button in your vie form..

```
function sendresume()
{

    $config['upload_path'] = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\application'; //path where to save in the systme
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf'; //file types to accept while uplaoding
    $config['max_size'] = '10240';  //size limit

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        echo "Resume Successfully uploaded to database.............";
        $file = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];  //upload file path
            }
   }
```