# Codeigniters do_upload() function is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

If I remove the part `$this->upload->do_upload('filefoto')` my data is saved into the database, but the image file is not saved to the folder path.

[enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/hHQgt1ap)

Copied from pastebin

```
public function tambahanggota() {    
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $nmfile = "file_".time();
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp';
    $config['max_size'] = '3072';
    $config['max_width']  = '5000';
    $config['max_height']  = '5000';
    $config['file_name'] = $nmfile;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
   
    if($_FILES['filefoto']['tmp_name'])
    {
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('filefoto'))
        {
            $gbr = $this->upload->data();
            $data = array(
           
            'nm_gbr' =>$gbr['file_name']                
            );

            $res = $this->M_tambahdata->tambahdata("anggota",$data);

            $config2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config2['source_image'] = $this->upload->upload_path.$this->upload->file_name;
            $config2['new_image'] = './assets/hasil_resize/';
            $config2['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config2['width'] = 100;
            $config2['height'] = 100;
            $this->load->library('image_lib',$config2);
           
            if ($res>=1) {

            echo "<script>alert('Data berhasil disimpan')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.location='".base_url()."dataanggota'</script>";
            }
                   
            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', 'Maaf, ulangi data gagal di inputkan.');
                redirect('dashboard/index');
            }
         
        }
    }
}
```

How can I upload my images?

Comment: see this;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642384/how-to-store-uploaded-file-into-folder-using-codeigniter

Comment: not working, can be save into database but in folder path is empty

Comment: localhost or public(shared) server?

Comment: On view have you used codeigniter form helper `form_open_multipart('controller/function')` and also try `if (isset($_FILES) {...}`

Comment: @Vickel  public(shared) server

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i have tried but the result is still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on a shared server hosting you may need to provide the **complete relative path** to your upload folder. Also make sure you have all permissions to write a file to that directory!

you can use on a localhost environment

```
$config['upload_path']   = './assets/upload';
```

but on a shared hosting, you'll need to get more specific, normally something like

```
$config['upload_path']   = '/home/yourserver/public_html/assets/upload';
```

You can find this upload_path, e.g. in your accounts cPanel main page on the left column or might want to call your provider's helpdesk for more info on the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

you missed this

```
$this->upload->upload_path.'/'.$this->upload->file_name;
```