# Codeigniter cannot upload image

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been googling around for 2-3 hours looking at every stackoverflow thread related to this. As far as I can see, lots of people share my frustration. Like many others, I cannot upload an image, even though it shows no errors.

I've literally tried anything and everything I found online, but nothing seems to work...

I can only see the properties of the image with var_dump($_FILES). I want to store the image into a folder and its name into a database.

**Controller**

```
function upload_sl()
{ 
    $config['upload_path'] = 'sliki/samurajsliki/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
/*$this->upload->initialize($config);*/
/*var_dump($_FILES);*/
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
  $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

  $this->load->view('samuraj/slikaclen', $error);
}
else
{
  $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

  $this->load->view('header_samurajmain');
  $this->load->view('samuraj/admin_samuraj');
  $this->load->view('footer_subpage');
}
}
```

**View**

```
<?php echo $error;?>
                   <div class="center-block" style="width: 30%; height: 50%; clear:both;">
                   <?php echo form_open_multipart('admin_page/upload_sl');?>
                    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

                    <br />

                    <input type="submit" value="Стави нова слика" />
                    </form>
                     </div>
```

Comment: Your upload path does not seem right.  It should be a full absolute server path... such as on shared hosting, it would be something like `home/account_name/www/my/path/to/folder`

Comment: it is most likely an issue with your path. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41604500/2275490

Comment: There was no error -_- just some server lag

Answer (score 1):

I found this in my archive. I don't know if its working.
Maybe you want to try it.

```
<form action="admin/#/add_content/do_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <input type="file" class="mb5" name="userfiles[]" multiple>
</form>
```

Here is Controller.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {           
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

        if($this->upload->do_upload()){
            echo "File ".$_FILES["userfile"]["name"]. " has been uploaded.\n";
        }
        else{
            //Error. this->upload->display_errors();
        }
    }
    header("Location: http://localhost:82/MyCRM/admin/#/add_content");
 }
 }
```

Comment: I use `form_open_multipart()` from form helper or in `action="<?php echo base_url('controller/upload_sl')"`

Answer (score 1):

Using the library Codeigniter ( [library upload single file and multi file](https://github.com/codeigniters/Uploads) ) Easily upload  .

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code. There was server lag and the folder where the images go wasn't refreshing on its own. Sorry for wasting everyone's time - I did check all of your answers.