# When uploading image in codeigniter the image is not saved into the path folder

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When I upload an image in Codeigniter its name is saved to the database but not in the default folder. I'am using Ajax to submit the image

My "view" profile

```
  <div id="timelineBackground">
<?php 

{
    $image_properties = array('src' => base_url("uploads/" . $timeline_image),'width' => '1000px','height'=> '400px','id'=>'coverimg', 'title' => 'That was quite a night','rel'   => 'lightbox');
    //echo img($image_properties);

   ?>
<div id="timelineselector">

<?php echo form_open_multipart('',["id"=>"form_cover"]); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ;?>" >

<?php echo form_upload(["name"=>"timelineimage"]); ?>

<?php echo form_submit(["name"=>"submit","value"=>"Submit"]); ?>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

</div><?php
}
?></div>
```

here is my ajax code

```
jQuery('#form_cover').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        var url= '<?php echo base_url("user/coverimage"); ?>';
        formData.value
        jQuery.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data)
            {

              $('#coverimg').attr('src',data);
            },
            error: function(data){
            //error function
            }
       });            
    });
```

my controller "user"

```
public function coverimage(){

  $config = [
      'upload_path' =>    './uploads/',
      'allowed_types' =>    'jpg|gif|png|jpeg',
      'max_size'            => 10000000000000,
      'max_width'            => 1024000000,
      'max_height'           => 7680000000,
                 ];

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if(!$this->upload->do_upload('timelineimage')  ) {
     $post = $this->input->post();
      unset($post['submit']);
       $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
     $file_name=$_FILES['timelineimage'];


      $this->load->model('Pmodel');
      $this->Pmodel->timeline_upload_model($post,$file_name);


        $image_properties = array(
        'src'   => base_url("./uploads/" . $file_name['name']),

        'width' => '200px',
        'height'=> '200px',
        'title' => 'That was quite a night',
        'rel'   => 'lightbox'
);

       // echo img($image_properties);
echo base_url("uploads/" . $file_name['name']);
     exit();
    }else {

      $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
      $this->load->view('admin/add_article',compact('upload_error'));
    }

}
```

my model "Pmodel"

```
    public function timeline_upload_model($arr,$arra)
{

    $email=$arr['email'];
    $image=$arra['name'];

$data=array('timelineimage'=>$image);

 $query=$this->db->where('email',$email)->update('user_data',$data);

    return $query;



}
```

Why does it only show the name but not the image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009648/codeigniter-cannot-upload-image/42011446#42011446

Comment: i found the problem the do_upload was  not working as well as the base url has some errors when returning images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and posted the code, in case anyone else wants to look at this...

the 'view'

```
 <div id="timelineBackground">
<?php 

{

    $image_properties = array('src' => base_url("uploads/" . $timeline_image),'width' => '1000px','height'=> '400px','id'=>'coverimg', 'title' => 'That was quite a night','rel'   => 'lightbox');
 echo img($image_properties);

   ?>
<div id="timelineselector">

<?php echo form_open_multipart('user/coverimage',["id"=>"form_cover"]); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ;?>" >

<?php echo form_upload(["name"=>"timelineimage"]); ?>

<?php echo form_submit(["name"=>"submit","value"=>"Submit"]); ?>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

</div><?php
}
?></div>

'ajax'

    jQuery('#form_cover').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        var url= '<?php echo base_url("user/coverimage"); ?>';
        formData.value
        jQuery.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data)
            {

              $('#coverimg').attr('src',data);
            },
            error: function(data){
            //error function
            }
       });            
    });
```

and the controller:

```
     public function coverimage()
  {
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_FILES);

      $config = [
                  'upload_path' =>    './uploads/',
                  'allowed_types' =>    'jpg|gif|png|jpeg',
                  'max_size'            => 10000000000000,
                  'max_width'            => 1024000000,
                  'max_height'           => 7680000000,
                ];
              $this->load->library('upload', $config);
              $this->upload->initialize($config); 
              $timelineimage="timelineimage";
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload($timelineimage)) 
         {
          $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->load->view('dashboard/profile',compact('upload_error'));


          }
          else 
          {

            $post = $this->input->post();
          unset($post['submit']);
          //print_r($post);

          $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
          //print_r($upload_data);

          $file_name=$_FILES['timelineimage'];
          $this->load->model('Pmodel');
          $this->Pmodel->timeline_upload_model($post,$file_name);


         $image_path= base_url("uploads/".$upload_data['raw_name'].$upload_data['file_ext']);

//echo base_url("uploads/" . $file_name['name']);

          }

  }
```